# Change the name of output of form-variables Django

Tags: html, django

I'm following [this Django guide](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-s7e_Fy6NRU&list=PL-osiE80TeTtoQCKZ03TU5fNfx2UY6U4p&index=10) for creating a "recipe" home-page, and I'm completly new to Django and html.

I am using the `CreateView` class for creating a new class of the instance `opskrift`

```py
class opskrift(models.Model):

    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    algorithm = models.TextField()
    time_taken = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    prep_time = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    n_persons = models.CharField(max_length=5)
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

with the view

```py
class OpskriftCreateView(CreateView): 
    model = opskrift
    fields = ["title","algorithm","time_taken","prep_time","n_persons"]
```

The problem is, that it displays the variable names i.e `n_persons`, `prep_time` on the homepage etc. but I would like to make it `Number of persons`, `Preperation time`.

Is there a way to do so using the template below

```html
{% extends "indkoeb/base.html" %}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}
{% block content %}
    <div class="content-section">
        <form method="OPSKRIFT">
            {% csrf_token %}
            <fieldset class="form-group">
                <legend class="border-bottom mb-4">New</legend>

                {{form|cripsy}}

            </fieldset>
            <div class="form-group">
                <button class="btn btn-outline-info" type="submit">Save</button>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
{% endblock content %}
```

Comment: show us your form

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class opskrift(models.Model):

title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
algorithm = models.TextField()
time_taken = models.CharField(max_length=10)
prep_time = models.CharField(max_length=10,verbose_name="Preperation time")
n_persons = models.CharField(max_length=5,verbose_name='Number of persons')
```